# How to define Ordering[Array[Byte]]?

Tags: scala

Is it necessary to provide the implementation from scratch? I could not find any matching implicit, not even in last-resort Implicits trait. `seqDerivedOrdering` obviously doesn't work, since `Array` is not a `Seq`.

Answer (score 8):

If you want it to be efficient, you'll have to write your own (this one handles nulls; if you can assume no nulls, just use the long else block):

```
val o = new math.Ordering[Array[Byte]] {
  def compare(a: Array[Byte], b: Array[Byte]): Int = {
    if (a eq null) {
      if (b eq null) 0
      else -1
    }
    else if (b eq null) 1
    else {
      val L = math.min(a.length, b.length)
      var i = 0
      while (i < L) {
        if (a(i) < b(i)) return -1
        else if (b(i) < a(i)) return 1
        i += 1
      }
      if (L < b.length) -1
      else if (L < a.length) 1
      else 0
    }
  }
}
```

Otherwise, you can `.toSeq` to package into a `WrappedArray` and defer to a Seq compare instead of doing your own scan.  (This will end up boxing and unboxing your bytes, which is why it's not efficient.  Since byte boxing is generally done by lookup in a table of all bytes, it's not *horribly* inefficent, so you may be able to get away with it unless you're doing e.g. heavy duty binary file processing.)

Comment: Yes, I wanted to add something like this, but wanted to ask before. Maybe it makes sense to add something to stdlib to make it more obvious?

Comment: @venechka - It would be nice if the `Array` object implemented these for each type.  Maybe someone should submit an enhancement request?  In the meantime, though, there are _lots_ of handy things that the standard library doesn't have.  You should get used to having your own personal standard library to fill in those pieces that you need!

Comment: it is enough to have a single @specialized version I think.

Comment: @venechka - In principle, yes.  In practice, I've hit enough bugs with specialized that I now no longer say it will solve a problem until I see it working.  If it works, it won't work trivially because you need `<` defined on the base type, and `Ordering` isn't specialized, so you can't just defer to that.  So you have to create your own specialized version of `Numeric` and work from there.

Comment: Anyway, looks like the performance penalty for using toSeq shouldn't be that bad

Answer (score 7):

If you're into brevity rather than raw performance:

```
scala> Ordering.by((_: Array[Byte]).toIterable)
res0: scala.math.Ordering[Array[Byte]] = scala.math.Ordering$$anon$7@8c9f531
```

Answer (score 2):

You can implement a very simple `Ordering` which calls `toSeq` on comapred array and calls then the `seqDerivedOrdering`. The conversion to a Seq should be nearly free in term of performances.